# C# Dynamically assign and update form during a method execution

Tags: c#, variables, dynamic, textbox, sudoku

How can I dynamically, during method's loops still working, assign values and make them update on the form? What happens in my program is, that when launched it hangs until it finishes (finds the solution to the sudoku) and then populates the Textboxes.
Here is the main method:

```
            bool SolveSudoku()
    {
        if (!FindUnassignedLocation()) return true;
        for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
        {
            if (NoConflicts(emptyRow, emptyCol, num))
            {
                Grid[emptyRow, emptyCol].Text = num.ToString();
                Grid[emptyRow, emptyCol].BackColor = Color.White;
                Grid[emptyRow, emptyCol].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                if (SolveSudoku()) return true;
                Grid[emptyRow, emptyCol].Text = "";   
            }
        }
        bool checkIfFirstBackTrack = true;
        do {
            if (checkIfFirstBackTrack)
            {
                backtrackCounter++;
                checkIfFirstBackTrack = false;
            }
            if (emptyCol == 0 && emptyRow > 0)
            {
                emptyCol = 8;
                emptyRow--;
            }
            else if (emptyCol > 0)
            {
                emptyCol--;
            }
        }
        while(Preset[emptyRow, emptyCol] != "");

        return false;
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Do you want the UI not to freeze during this operation?

Comment: could it be that you do a do while loop ?

Comment: @TrackmeifYouCan: yes I do have a do while loop.

Comment: so maybe there is another part of the code that you should show here to make it clearer where your problem is, where is your do while ?

Comment: @TrackmeifYouCan: This do while is there to prevent changing preset values in sudoku grid during backtracking.

Comment: I guess you got a nice solution down there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be a background worker [See more information on setting up a background worker here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx):

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            //// your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't the background worker also 'act frozen' until it completed its process? And then, I guess I wouldnt be able to capture variables being changed and dynamically assign them into form.

Comment: "The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a separate, dedicated thread. Time-consuming operations like downloads and database transactions can cause your user interface (UI) to seem as though it has stopped responding while they are running. When you want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a convenient solution."

Comment: I just read some things about BackgroundWorkers and cross-thread calls to Windows Forms and it seems that you cannot safely assign the values when the process is running, but only after completing the process - which eliminates the possibility of dynamical assignment, right?

Comment: This is true you can free up the form but you can not assign to the form or you will have problems, this true no matter how you do it.

Comment: So you mean there is **no way** in which I can make these boxes filled right after they are filled in the code?

Comment: What is the Grid you are using? Does it have Invalidate method? I would think you could try to Invalidate the grid after you add a value but it will flicker with it repainting after every addition.

Comment: `RichTextBox[,] Grid = new RichTextBox[9, 9];`
Its basically a grid of textboxes, which i further linked to this Array.

Comment: You can try this.Invalidate(); after you add each entry, but again it will flicker I think.